# Tools required to build a human resource management website

Tags: python, django

If this is not the correct forum to ask this question, please suggest any other forum.

we need to design a mini Human resource management website to manage few employees.

basically a view which gives an employee to login and do below actions

option to declare tax exceptions like 80c,d etc

option to see and download payslips/income tax statements etc

option to edit/request to change his personal/professional information

Another admin view where whether admin to allow/verify the details, edit employee settings etc.

I don't have much experience with web development. i am good with python and i have bit experience with Django framework. i see few tutorials for creating websites using Django framework.

Edit:
Any other easy way to do this other than using Django framework?

Comment: Why not just ask us to recommend one which is free & open-source?

Comment: @Mawg: Yes, you are right. I am doing this for my own purpose. If the tools are open source it will help us lot.;